# merging pdf's with duplicate form field names

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, pdftk

I created a PDF in Word / Adobe Acrobat that has two identically named form field names. That PDF can be found here:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/test.pdf

When I open that PDF with Google Chrome I can edit those fields as I see fit. However, when I then run that pdf through pdftk with `pdftk test.pdf cat output test2.pdf` and then try to open the new PDF - test2.pdf - with Google Chrome I can't edit either of the fields.

Here's test2.pdf:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/test2.pdf

Any ideas as to what my options are? I want to be able to merge the test.php with other PDFs and have the form fields still be editable in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In test2.pdf `/Creator pdftk 1.41`. I tested your command with pdftk 2.02 version -- it creates valid PDF. Time to upgrade?